# Emacs' default `expand-abbrev` does not work

Tags: abbrev

I try to use `emacs -Q` and then input `RET RET dd` in `*scratch*` buffer and then `M-x add-mode-abbrev`,
then after the prompting message `Mode abbrev for "dd":`, I input `abcdefg RET`.

So I defined an mode specific abbrev, but when I try to `expand-abbrev` when putting point after the previously input `dd`, nothing happened, even no warning messages.

My Emacs version is "GNU Emacs 25.1.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0)
 of 2016-10-03".

Did I use `expand-abbrev` in a wrong way? Or does `expand-abbrev` of this version break?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for **`inverse-add-mode-abbrev`**, not `add-mode-abbrev`.

If you want to expand `dd` to `abcdefg` then use `M-x inverse-add-mode-abbrev` with the cursor after `dd`.

Command `add-mode-abbrev` defines an abbreviation for the last word.  For instance, if the text in the buffer is `george` and you use `M-x add-mode-abbrev` with the cursor after that text, and then you type `gg` at the prompt then you have defined abbreviation `gg` for the word `george`.

In your case, you apparently want to define `dd` as an abbreviation for `abcdefg`, so you need to use `inverse-add-mode-abbrev`.